# Make button as marker in imageview

Tags: android

I have an image in a custom imageview, which is a layout of a building. I need to add buttons(or markers like in google maps) in few places on the image with a longclick or drag and drop a button from the top of the screen. How the button(or marker) comes doesnt matter, but the main problem is im unable to get it on top of an image. I want it just like a marker on google map, should be able to perform onclick and onlongclick operations. Should even be able to delete it. After that i need to save my image with those buttons i added in order to load it the next time my app launches, just like my saved places in google maps.

Can anyone please suggest me a best way to do it. I am new to android and I am sorry if the same question has already been asked, I would appreciate if u can give me a link to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your codes!

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

[Subsampling Scale Image View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)

It supports zooming/panning, adding pins or draw over image and lots more. This can solve your preview related issues, but you need to store your data manually. In that case you can use [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Hope this will be helpful.